# javascript fetch is not posting to rest api endpoint while postman is doing

Tags: javascript, jquery, fetch-api

I have a `rest api endpoint` and I am checking it using `POSTMAN` which is posting correctly. But, when I am doing it using JAVASCRIPT FETCH, I am not able to post it. Below is my code for fetch:

```
const { inputAOI, wktForCreation } = this.state

fetch('http://192.168.1.127:8080/aoi/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ userName: 'fuseim', aoiName: inputAOI, wkt: wktForCreation }),
      mode: 'no-cors'
    }).then(function (response) {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json()
      } else {
        throw new Error('Could not reach the API: ' + response.statusText)
      }
    }).then(function (data) {
      console.log({ data })
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log({ error })
    })
```

Below is the image for the request headers.
[image: error image]

It is seen in the above image that in `Request Headers`, the `Content-Type` is still `text/plain` but I am sending `application/json` as shown in above fetch code.

Check the response preview in console.
[image: error 2 image]

Below is correct POSTMAN request:
[image: postman image]

Comment: Does the API have a guard blocking requests sent with mode: no-cors? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Try sending it without that parameter

Comment: "[no-cors — Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET or POST, and the __headers from being anything other than simple headers__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode)"

Answer (score 1):

As hinted in the comments, the problem is with the `mode:"no-cors"`

Content-Type is considered a simple header, and should be allowed without cors, **but** only with the following values:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data
- text/plain

See: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#simple-header

If you are running the API on the same host/port as the script, you should use `mode: "same-origin"` alternatively add the host/port that the script is running on as an allowed origin on the API.

For more information about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

`headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}`

you could try:

`headers: new Headers({
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
})`

Comment: The two are equivalent, they will result to the same thing